# notifyItemInserted does not show animation

Tags: android

It appears to be that notifyItemInserted() does not show the default recycleview animation. Here is My code:

```
    .
    .
    .
    private List<String> mDataSet = new ArrayList<>(0);
    .
    .
    .
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Brain.context);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mDataSet);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    .
    .
    .
    mDataSet.add("");
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mDataSet.size() - 1);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It shows the data fine, only thing missing is the animation?

Comment: @asco Yes, only thing missing is the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`